# Chrome how to disable debugger keyword or disable pause

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know there is a `Never pause here`, but it's not works for code like this

```
setInterval(function(){
  eval('debugger;'+Math.random())
},1000)
```

If I can't find the `setInterval`, I can not disable the pause, it's very annoying.

Is there any flag or somehow to disable this ?

**EDIT**

I found this [issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429167)(DevTools: impossible to disable a breakpoint caused by "debugger" statement) relate to this problem, in the test [code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/8349ee0c269d527d1d1c6f11a685ee4ee221720d/test/mjsunit/debug-negative-break-points.js) I found a flag `--expose-debug-as debug`, but how can I use this flag for headless,

```
chrome --expose-debug-as debug --headless --disable-gpu '<URL>' --repl
[0610/020053.677043:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(459)] Open multiple tabs is only supported when the remote debug port is set.
```

Comment: Um, delete the code.... ;)

Comment: @epascarello That's not an option, it's not my work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the only choice you really have is to inject code into the page that overrides eval and removes it.

```
(function () {
  var _eval = window.eval;
  window.eval = function (str) {
    _eval(str.replace(/debugger;/,""));
  };
}());
eval("debugger;alert('a');")
```

Comment: Sounds good, I also trying to clear all intervals, eval replace may cause script broken, because some compiler use eval to encrypt code.

Comment: Note that overriding `eval` will break code that creates variables outside of its internal scope i.e. in the callee scope - only the built-in `eval` can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I done this by disable interval and timeout, some site use this to prevent others watching code.

I insert code before onload by using chrome headless

Start headless

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu <URL> --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Other shell session

```
yarn add chrome-remote-interface
```

**test.es6**

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
async function test() {
  const protocol = await CDP({port: 9222});
  // Extract the DevTools protocol domains we need and enable them.
  // See API docs: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/
  const {Page, Runtime, Debugger, Log, Console} = protocol;
  try {
      await Promise.all([
          Page.enable(),
          Runtime.enable(),
          Log.enable(),
          Console.enable(),
          Debugger.disable(),
      ]);
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Failed', e)
      return
  }

  Log.entryAdded(({entry: e}) =>
      console.log(`${new Date(e.timestamp).toISOString()} ${e.source}:${e.level} ${e.text}`)
  );
  Console.messageAdded(({message: e}) =>
      console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} ${e.source}:${e.level} ${e.text}`)
  )
  Page.navigate({url: URL_HERE});
  // Inject code,disable setInterval and setTimeout
  Runtime.executionContextCreated(async ({context}) => {
      console.log('executionContextCreated')
      let result = await Runtime.evaluate({
          expression: `
          window._si=window.setInterval
          window.setInterval=(...args)=>{
              let id = 1//window._si.apply(window,args)
              console.warn(\`setInterval:\${args}\`,)
              return id
          }

          window._st=window.setTimeout
          window.setTimeout=(...args)=>{
              let id = 1//window._st.apply(window,args)
              console.warn(\`setTimeout:\${args}\`,)
              return id
          }
          ;location.href
          `,
          contextId: context.id,
      });
      console.log('executionContextCreated', result)
  });
  // Wait for window.onload before doing stuff.
  Page.loadEventFired(async () => {

      // Debugger.setSkipAllPauses(true)
      const js = `
      console.log('Page load');
      document.querySelector('title').textContent
      `;
      // Evaluate the JS expression in the page.
      const result = await Runtime.evaluate({expression: js});
      console.log('Title of page: ' + result.result.value);
      protocol.close();
  });
}
test()
```

After script, open 'localhost:9222' in chrome, inspect the page, the debugger not run now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need setInterval for anything else, just type this in the console:

```
window.setTimeout = null
```