# How can I disable only the "debugger" keyword in chrome, that gets executed by an eval inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I want to disable only the 'debugger' keyword through out the whole debugging process.
I am debugging a script that is obfuscated and that uses an eval to spawn a [VM] which then, this [VM] has a set interval with another eval that also has the debugger keyword, which gets executed quite a few times (my guessing would be at least hundreds of times).

---

Ways to replicate: Clone https://github.com/krpar/pooky-browser, and from the README use the pooky from week 10. Afterwards, run "node index.js", open devtools and enable breakpoints

---

What I have in mind: Get chromium source code, edit the 'debugger' keyword so it has no actual purpose.
Why this is not efficient: Compiling takes 13 hours on my machine; I do not exactly know how I will do this; I will use this as a last resort;

---

I've looked over [Chrome how to disable debugger keyword or disable pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463814/chrome-how-to-disable-debugger-keyword-or-disable-pause) and I've seen Wener answer, I am not sure if I can successfully replicate this, because the repository that I've cloned already "injects" pooky.js script into the supremenewyork.com website

I've also tried looking for more answers but they are just desabling all breakpoints or trying to blackbox the script; downsides of this: I tried using 'never stop here' but as it gets executed by an eval, it has no use

---

This code is from the first [VM] that is spawned

```js
(function() {
    (function a() {
        var c = new Date().valueOf();
        eval(" try { setTimeout(a, 2000); (function b () { debugger; if((R0ggg() - this) > 30) { b.call(R0ggg()); } }).call(R0ggg()); } catch (e) { } ");
        if ((new Date().valueOf() < c) || (new Date().valueOf() - c) > 1062) {
            var k0gggg = 2;
            for (; k0gggg !== 1; ) {
                switch (k0gggg) {
                case 2:
                    (function() {
                        var D3wg = 2;
                        for (; D3wg !== 7; ) {
                            switch (D3wg) {
                            case 3:
                                return;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                D3wg = p3wg[t3wg] ? 3 : 9;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                var X3wg = "u";
                                X3wg += "n";
                                X3wg += "d";
                                X3wg += "e";
                                X3wg += "f";
                                X3wg += "i";
                                X3wg += "n";
                                X3wg += "e";
                                X3wg += "d";
                                var t3wg = "_";
                                t3wg += "p";
                                t3wg += "Z";
                                t3wg += "6";
                                t3wg += "R";
                                t3wg += "H";
                                t3wg += "z";
                                t3wg += "K";
                                t3wg += "3";
                                t3wg += "L";
                                t3wg += "T";
                                t3wg += "1";
                                t3wg += "I";
                                var p3wg = typeof window !== X3wg ? window : typeof global !== X3wg ? global : this;
                                D3wg = 4;
                                break;
                            case 9:
                                try {
                                    var J3wg = 2;
                                    for (; J3wg !== 1; ) {
                                        switch (J3wg) {
                                        case 2:
                                            AtCB();
                                            J3wg = 1;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (S3wg) {}
                                p3wg[t3wg] = function() {}
                                ;
                                D3wg = 7;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }());
                    k0gggg = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    )()
}
)();
```

I expect for my google chrome devtools to not stop at the 'debugger' keyword

Comment: then remove it from your code ...

Comment: What a rabbit hole https://www.wired.com/2017/05/using-bots-to-buy-supreme-limited-edition-streetwear/ I still barely understand what this is

Comment: @Bravo I don't think I can, I can't find the eval that spawns the first [VM], the whole file is obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty hacky idea, but one possibility would be to monkeypatch `window.eval` which replaces all instances of `debugger` with nothing before the script runs. In `index.js`, right above the first `addScriptTag` call, put:

```
await page.addScriptTag({content: `
  const origEval = window.eval;
  window.eval = (str) => {
    const replaced = str.replace(/debugger/g, 'undefined');
    return origEval(replaced);
  };
`});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. I've tried it the only downside is that it doesn't stop at manually placed breakpoints.

Comment: Cool, it works! How are you placing your manual breakpoints? If you're editing them directly into a .`js`, you can add some special syntax around it to make sure it doesn't get ignored

Comment: I'm placing the manual breakpoints clicking the line number inside google devtools after beautifying the whole pooky.js file. I navigate the website making sure the cookies generated by pooky.js change but the script never seems to stop at the breakpoints placed

Comment: You should make sure the "debugger" is not a part of a string too.