# Remove anonymous debugger from Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

A while ago I was working on a webapp and for the purpose of debugging I've added a listener function directly in the console of Chrome Dev Tools and I've included a js `debugger` keyword in it to have a breakpoint there.

Now I can't get rid of that debugger and whenever I try inspecting the page, click on `Select an element in the page to incspect it` and I click anywhere on the page to take me to that node in the DOM structure I'm entering the breakpoint and I need to `Continue script execution` multiple times.

The debugged code looks like this:

[image]

I've tried triggering `Never pause here` option on each possible line, but it just opens a new VMxxxxx file. The breakpoint is not available in the Breakpoints list so I can't remove or uncheck it from there. Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome how to disable debugger keyword or disable pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463814/chrome-how-to-disable-debugger-keyword-or-disable-pause) See also [Is it possible to avoid breaking on a debugger statement in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972086)

Comment: The first thread is not exactly my case - I wasn't using interval or eval so overriding/disabling them won't do the trick. I tried the solution from the other thread and it didn't work either

Comment: Apparently it's bound to `mousedown` or `click` or some other mouse event. You can see them in the Event Listeners panel and click the `remove` button. Try also searching the source code for `debugger` keyword.

Comment: It's not part of the actual source code, its being added by devtools somehow. Can I search through sources in devtools based on file content? All I'm seeing is searching by name. And as I mentioned i have no breakpoints listed in the Event Listeners panel.

Comment: Devtools doesn't add such things. It's added by the site to prevent inspection. The site may obfuscate the code though so you won't find it. The Event Listeners panel doesn't list breakpoints, it lists events - it's the one in the Elements tab of devtools. Make sure to enable the "ancestors" and "framework" checkboxes.

Comment: You were right - it is added by the page! Haven't event realized devtools is working properly on different sites. In Elements tab I have a bunch of events, not sure which one is guilty of causing me problems but yeah, that should be it so thanks!

Comment: Feel free to add your comment as the post answer, i'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: @wOxxOm slight update: it's actually not site related - I've opened chrome with new user-data-dir paremeter from the terminal ale the page loads normally, I can access the dev tools without entering any breakpoints

Comment: The site may add it conditionally. It may be added by an extension you have in the main profile.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, i found that one of my browser extentions was throwing the anonymous debugger. I solved the problem by disabling all my extentions, confirming the anonymous debugger issue went away and then reenabled one extention at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can Deactivate breakpoints by Ctrl+F8. This will deactivate all breakpoints in javascript.

Comment: Function stops debugger even without a breakpoint, is used to avoid the suer debug the page by stopping when the Developer tools is open.